# Python remove item from list if present in other list

Tags: python, string, list, while-loop

I have scraped some data as strings and appended it into two separate lists.

I would like to delete an `item` (while `item` can be included several times) from a list called `list_creatures_BP` if it is present in another list called `list_bosses_BP`.

This is my code:

```
# append creatures to creatures list
for creatue in result_creatures_bp:
    list_creatures_BP.append(creatue.text)


# append bosses to bosses list
for boss in result_bosses_bp:
    list_bosses_BP.append(boss.text)


# delete bosses from creatures list
for item in list_creatures_BP:
    if item in list_bosses_BP:
        while item in list_creatures_BP:
            list_creatures_BP.remove(item)
```

But the item is still present in both lists.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean:

```
newlist = []
for item in list_creatures_BP:
    if item not in list_bosses_BP:
        newlist.append(item)
```

Or just:

```
newlist = [item for item in list_creatures_BP if item not in list_bosses_BP]
```

The reason your code doesn't work is because:

- You have an while loop with `remove`, `remove` behaves unexpectedly in loops, it will always right shift and it will modify the list incorrectly.

Comment: If you aren't going to look for duplicates for common problems like this, please at least explain the problem in the answer instead of just giving code.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Alright